# SSH into private host machine Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

Public IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (This is working to get direct access to public VM: `webserver-1 ansible_port=50003 ansible_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ansible_user=ronak ansible_ssh_private_key_file=priv_key`)

Private IP: 10.0.2.4 (`ssh ronak@10.0.2.4`)

```
                                  ssh                          ssh
vagrant host ----> public host (port: 50003) ----> private host (port: 22)
                                   ^                             ^
                                using A's                     using B's
                                ssh priv key                   PASSWORD
```

**hosts:**

```
[database]
dbserver-1 ansible_port=22 ansible_host=10.0.2.4 ansible_user=ronak ansible_ssh_pass=password
```

**dbserver.yml:**

```
- hosts: "database"
  remote_user: ronak
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ./priv_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p ronak@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 50003"'
  roles:
    - dbserver
```

**Error:**

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/Ansible$ ansible-playbook dbserver.yml -vvv
Using /var/www/Ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

task path: /var/www/Ansible/roles/dbserver/tasks/main.yml:2
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/packaging/os/apt.py
<10.0.2.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ronak
<10.0.2.4> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o User=ronak -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -i ./priv_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p ronak@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 50003' -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/dbabe40296 10.0.2.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.2.4> (5, '', "Warning: Permanently added '10.0.2.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\n")
<10.0.2.4> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ronak
<10.0.2.4> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22 -o User=ronak -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -i ./priv_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p ronak@xx.xx.xx.xx -p 50003' -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/dbabe40296 10.0.2.4 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1495038139.56-230805529478418 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1495038139.56-230805529478418="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1495038139.56-230805529478418 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.0.2.4> (5, '', "Warning: Permanently added '10.0.2.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied, please try again.\r\n")
fatal: [dbserver-1]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Authentication failure.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
inventory         = ./hosts
ask_sudo_pass     = True
host_key_checking = False

[paramiko_connection]
record_host_keys = False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

**ANSIBLE_DEBUG**

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.2.4' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
<<<

4156 1495119116.27802: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
<<<

4156 1495119116.27876: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
<<<

4156 1495119116.27929: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
<<<

4156 1495119116.37456: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
<<<

4156 1495119116.40286: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<<<

4156 1495119116.40710: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 57 padlen 7 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
<<<

4156 1495119118.39890: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
<<<
```

**10.0.4.2 log /var/log/auth.log**

```
May 18 15:03:16 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51082]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.1.5  user=ronak
May 18 15:03:18 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51082]: Failed password for ronak from 10.0.1.5 port 49234 ssh2
May 18 15:03:18 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51082]: Failed password for ronak from 10.0.1.5 port 49234 ssh2
May 18 15:03:18 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51082]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.5 port 49234 [preauth]
May 18 15:03:20 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51086]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.1.5  user=ronak
May 18 15:03:22 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51086]: Failed password for ronak from 10.0.1.5 port 49236 ssh2
May 18 15:03:22 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51086]: Connection closed by 10.0.1.5 port 49236 [preauth]
```

Comment: Your "error" doesn't really indicate an error, unless you have a particular reason to think that control socket should be there. What actually happens when you run ansible?

Comment: @Kenster: I am trying to ssh into private IP and ansible stops after giving this error.

Comment: @Kenster: Uodated my question with exact error message.. host is unreachable.

Comment: what about doing `ssh ronak@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -i ./priv_key -p 50003` from outside the VNET?

Comment: @fernandezcuesta: That one is working .. But, from that I want to get access to another VM which only has private ip.

Comment: yes, I understood that's the scenario. Can you paste the output with `-vvv` flags enabled (obfuscate as required)?

Comment: @fernandezcuesta: Uploaded the screenshot of the error.

Comment: try unhiding ssh errors replacing `-q` with `-vvv` in the `ProxyCommand` arguments

Comment: @fernandezcuesta: Yes.. updated in second image.

Comment: @RonakPatel I still see the `-q` there. BTW please post plain text instead images.

Comment: `Permission denied` means that the server found no valid authentication from those provided. Please doublecheck that you're using the correct key. Try connecting with `ssh ronak@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -i ./priv-key -p50003 -F /dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -vvv` to see if that key (`./priv-key`) is actually valid.

Comment: are you sure, the path ``./priv-key`` relative from the ansible working directory is correct? Try putting an absolute path there. If it works, you can test if i.e. ``~/priv-key`` works or determine the relative path from the ansible workdir, if you really need a relative path.

Comment: Actually I missed adding private key in previous one. Updated new error again.. Also `ansible.cfg` file

Comment: @allo: Path is correct

Comment: @fernandezcuesta: Tried that way as well.. Still getting the same error. Updated the question a bit. Please take a look.

Comment: Could you not tunnel into port 50003, and then ssh against a port on localhost?

Comment: Execute playbook as `ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook -vvvv dbserver.yml`. Paste ansible output log part between `Warning: Permanently added...` and `Permission denied...`. Also paste relevant part of `/var/log/auth.log` from `10.0.2.4` host.

Comment: @mahatmanich: No. Actually, 50003 is forwarded to 80 internally (Azure settings)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: I have updated the question with those 2 things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sshd log:

```
May 18 15:03:20 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51086]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.1.5  user=ronak
May 18 15:03:22 dev-db-VM0 sshd[51086]: Failed password for ronak from 10.0.1.5 port 49236 ssh2
```

I think that the problem is with incorrect password for `ronak` account.

Please make sure that you set it correctly (copy and paste it again into your config files).
Also make sure that there are no variables [priority](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) collision.
You can try to execute playbook with `-e ansible_ssh_pass=password` to ensure the highest priority for password settings.

P.S. I've mimicked your environment in virtual box and everything works ok with similar setup.

Comment: `ansible_ssh_pass` is already defined in hosts file. see the question. But, somehow it's not being pulled in `ProxyCommand`. How to use that password in proxycommand?

Comment: Yes, I saw hosts files. Your proxy command doesn't need password – it works with privkey file, not password. Password is used only for second connection. You may have some other variable level that have other `ansible_ssh_pass` defined, so I advised to try with `-e` to be sure.

Comment: Thanks! It's working perfect now. So, that's the only way to provide password. right? From command itself? And also can you please update your answer in case if we are using private key instead of password, it'll be great help!

Comment: To work with key auth you can use `-e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=key_file`. But this is not recommended way. I just showed you how to overcome/debug your authentication issue. If setting password via extra variable (`-e`) worked for you, you should inspect your environment where `ansible_ssh_pass` may override your inventory value (maybe role's variable or something else).